# Limit the maximum number of characters in a double

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, double

Is there an elegant way to convert a double to a string so it's rounded to fit within a maximum total length but is otherwise similar to the default neutral culture format?

I don't want to just limit the number of decimal places because the number of characters used for sign and exponent might change, or it might not be in scientific notation.

Eg, with a maximum of 20 characters

```
-1.23456789012345E-67
```

should appear as

```
-1.2345678901235E-67
```

while

`123` should appear as `123`, not `1.23E+02`.

Comment: [`G`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) format should produce the most *compact* string representation. You may want to implement own formatter (as extension method for `double` to example), which will do all your logic: converting, checking, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Sintar mentioned G format specifier should do all you need.

```
double s = 1.31956544564371E+28;
Console.WriteLine("{0:G5}",s);  // will print 1.3196E+28
```

The following is a extension method might be helpful:

```
public static class doubleExtensions
{
    public static string GetDoubleString(this double source,int numOfChars){
        string  temp = "{0:G" + numOfChars + "}";
        return string.Format(temp,source);
    }
}
```

Comment: This just controls the number of significant figures, not characters. Eg. -1.2345678E-123 becomes -1.2346E-123 (12 chars) but 1234.5678 becomes 1234.6 (6 chars).